# MySQL Using foreign Key to visit parent row?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, inner-join

my table 'article_keywords' has a row called 'keyword_id' that references 'id' column of 'keywords' table. from 'article_keywords' table's 'keyword_id' column, is there a way to directly access that row of 'keywords' table without querying the 'id' in 'keywords table?'

Comment: Search for MYSQL JOIN

Comment: Not sure what you mean - foreign keys are constraints which will check that a keywords_id exists on an INSERT or UPDATE to article_keywords without you coding anything further. That's as much as foreign key constraints will do for you. If you want to get any data from keywords in a select you need to use a join of some sort.

Comment: Thank you! JOIN was what i was looking for! Though i expected JOIN to be better in terms of performance than SELECT + WHERE, it seems like there isn't much of a difference..

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for a JOIN between both tables.

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    k.*
FROM 
    article_keywords a
    INNNER JOIN keywords k
        ON k.id = a.keyword_id
WHERE
    ...
```